# Is all traffic through a router configured to use openvpn protocol sent through a single port?

Tags: vpn, router, openvpn

A home wifi router is configured to use a vpn service, such as PIA, and in particular is configured to use the openvpn protocol. Is all traffic through this router sent through a single port?

Is the following an accurate representation of the flow of traffic between a computer behind a vpn router and a website? (Also is that the correct usage of 'vpn router'?).

Computer sends data to router >> router encrypts data and sends it to vpn server >> vpn server decrypts data and sends it to its destination (e.g. a website)

(reverse)

website sends data to vpn server >> vpn server encrypts data and sends it to router >> router decrypts data and sends it to computer

Thanks for any help in advance. I need this question answered so that I can ask my next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's exactly as you are thinking.

A VPN connection works just like a proxy: every single connection is encapsulated in another one, connecting your router to the VPN server.

For an external observer, you will have only one very long-lived outgoing connection.

Comment: Thanks. And so, from the router, data is only sent through a single port, correct? Sorry if that's obvious. I just need to check.

Comment: @JonDoe If you are talking about port on the external network, from the router to the VPN service is only one port. For the internal network, all ports are fair game.